# Mule: How Can I insert a database sequence into a table?

Tags: mule

I am trying to insert a database sequence into a table will this work?

```
     <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="INSERT Table">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO 
    XX.XX_OE_OBJ_HDR 
   (ATTRIBUTE1,
    MY_ID,
    MY_NUMBER)   
    values (
    #[payload.id],
    XX.XX_HDR_SEQ,
    XX.XX_HDR_NUM_SEQ
    )]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

I get the following error:

```
    org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:   

    Message               : ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Mule question. Oracle tells you that your sql is wrong.
Try to run it in sqlplus and you will see:

```
INSERT INTO 
    XX.XX_OE_OBJ_HDR 
   (ATTRIBUTE1,
    MY_ID,
    MY_NUMBER)   
    values (
    abc,
    XX.XX_HDR_SEQ,
    XX.XX_HDR_NUM_SEQ
    )
```

Perhaps ATTRIBUTE1 is a number, not a varchar. Cast this value to appropriate type.